# clr table valued functions

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, clr

I created this clr table valued functions in VB.NET using VS 2017 and sql 2014:

```
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Partial Public Class UserDefinedFunctions

    <SqlFunction(DataAccess:=DataAccessKind.Read, FillRowMethodName:="my_FillRow", TableDefinition:="Name nchar(27)")>
    Public Shared Function getNames() As IEnumerable
        Dim strConn As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Nothing
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        Dim Name As SqlString
        Dim resultCollection As New ArrayList()


        strConn = "Server=localhost\myserver;" +
                    "Database=Test;" +
                    "User ID=user;" +
                    "Password=pwd;"

        cmd = New SqlCommand("select top 10 Name from tblNames", New SqlConnection(strConn))
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 240
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            Name = reader.GetSqlString(1)
            resultCollection.Add(New DataRec(Name))
        End While

        Return resultCollection
    End Function

    Private Class DataRec
        Public Name As SqlString

        Public Sub New(Name As SqlString)
            Me.Name= Name
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Sub my_FillRow(dataObj As Object, ByRef Name As SqlString)
        Dim rec As DataRec = DirectCast(dataObj, DataRec)

        Name = rec.Name
    End Sub
End Class
```

after creating assembly and function

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyTot
FROM 'C:\source\repos\udf-sql-01\udf-sql-01\bin\Debug\udf-sql-01.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
GO  
  
CREATE FUNCTION getNames()   
RETURNS TABLE (  
   Name nchar(27)  
)  
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyTot.UserDefinedFunctions.getNames;  
go
```

and try function:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.getNames();
```

i get this error:

```
Messaggio 6522, livello 16, stato 1, riga 28
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "getNames": 
System.Security.SecurityException: Richiesta di autorizzazione di tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' non soddisfatta.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   in System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   in System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
   in System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.DemandPermission()
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   in System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   in UserDefinedFunctions.FindInvalidEmails()
```

The sql instance and visual studio are on the same pc.
I have tried with a sql user and with a windows user (both user are correctly configured on sql). The sql instance is configured for mixed authentication (windows and sql).

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making a non-context connection requires EXTERNAL_ACCESS permission for the stored procedure.

So change

```
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
```

to

```
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
```

Or if that is the same instance that hosts the CLR, use a [Context Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/data-access/context-connection?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of opening a regular SqlConnection.